# python list comprehension double for but keep grouping form

Tags: python-3.x, nested, iteration, list-comprehension

I have the following list

```
grouping = [[('Amy',1),('Bob',2)],[('Cindy',3)]]
```

I hope I can extract the name but keep the grouping form

```
[['Amy','Bob'],['Cindy']]
```

I try to use

```
result = [x[0] for b in grouping for x in b]
```

but it will give me ['Amy','Bob','Cindy'] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each sublist in `grouping`, you want to make a new list made up of the 0th elements of each constituent tuple.  So:

```
>>> grouping = [[('Amy',1),('Bob',2)],[('Cindy',3)]]
>>> [x[0] for b in grouping for x in b]
['Amy', 'Bob', 'Cindy']
>>> [[x[0] for x in b] for b in grouping]
[['Amy', 'Bob'], ['Cindy']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a powerful way. I didn't know I can have another bracket inside the bracket!